# Use IBOutlet in Function in Header File

Tags: objective-c, function, ios4, iboutlet

could you please tell me how i can use IBOutlets in a function stored in the header file:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>    

@interface MainView : UIView <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>  {

        IBOutlet UILabel *SoundDescriptionLabel;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *StopSoundButton;

}
- (IBAction)PlayFatGuyWalking:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayRoadRunner:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)ShowInfoPopup:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayChaosRunning:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlaySadTrombone:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayBadJokeSound:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayHorrorSynth:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayLKWPeep:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)PlayUiToll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)StopSound:(id)sender;



AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;



@end


//PlaySound Function
void playSound(NSString *filename,NSString *type){
    [theAudio stop];    
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:type];
    theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
//HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DO THIS:
StopSoundButton.enabled=1;
//END OF WHAT I'D LIKE TO DO
        [theAudio play];
    }
```

Please help me

thx in advance

Comment: just out of curiosity..: why do you want to solve this using a function as opposed to using a regular method?

Comment: i'm just learning objective-c..how would i do this as a method? :(

Answer (score 1):

An IBOutlet has no impact or effect on your code - it's #defined out!

It is used as a suggestion to Interface Builder, which can parse the header, so that it knows that that variable can become linked to some graphical control in some way.